# Update multiple rows in database based on multiple checkboxes and inputs

Tags: php, mysql

I have array below and I need to update database according to this.
It should be something like example code below but I don't know how to do it correctly:

```
UPDATE productPercent SET percent="$percent" WHERE 
store="$store" AND 
startDate>"$start_date" AND 
endDate<"$end_date" AND 
storeGroup="$storeGroup" AND 
productGroup="$product_group" AND 
productName LIKE '$search%'
```

I need to check for each store, store group, product (if contains word) and product group and then update productPercent table. Percent, product group, store group, product name and store are in different tables so some kind of inner join is needed.
I need some directions regarding this because I don't know how to start, thank you.

```
Array
(
    [percent] => 3
    [store] => Array
        (
            [0] => 36
            [1] => 45
            [2] => 56
        )

    [start_date] => 2015-02-09
    [end_date] => 2015-03-31
    [storeGroup] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 4
        )

    [product_group] => Array
        (
            [0] => 13
            [1] => 31
            [2] => 32
        )

    [search] => iphone
    [setPercent] => Submit
)
```

UPDATED: data model - tableName: columns(connected tables)

***store***: id,name,startDate,endDate
**storeGroup**: id,storeGroupID(in table storeGroupName: id,name),storeID
**productGroup**: id,productID(in table productName: id,name),groupID(in table productGroupName: id,name)
**productName**: id,name
**productPercent**: id,productID,storeID,percent

Comment: Can you provide your data model please?

Answer (score 0):

```
$pdoHandle = $this->getPDOHandle();
$searchword = 'iphone';
$sql = "UPDATE 
productPercent 
inner join store on productPercent.storeID=store.id
inner join storeGroup on storeGroup.storeID=store.id
inner join productGroup on productGroup.id=storeGroup.groupID
inner join productName on productPercent.productID=productName.id and productGroup.productID=productName.id

SET percent=:percent
WHERE productName.name like :searchword";


$pdo->prepare($sql);
$pdo->setAttribute('percent', floatval($percent/100));
$pdo->setAttribute('searchword', $searchword . '%');
```

Comment: Thank you. I have few questions as I am not too familiar with pdo. What does first line of code represent? Because I am getting _Using $this when not in object context_ and am confused with this line: `inner join productGroup on productGroup.id=storeGroup.groupID` because storeGroup doesn't have groupID